# Include Materializecss into Angular2 project with Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, materialize, angular2-material

I'm pretty new to Angular2 and its ecosystem, and I try to figure out how things work together. Sorry if some questions seem trivial.

So I deployed a fresh new Angular2 app, with the help of [AngularClass starter kit](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter), which uses Webpack.

For the UI, I wanted to use Material instead of Bootstrap. I did some research and I started to be lost among tons of projects around Material. What I'm looking for is :

- an easy way to use Material css and classes, like grid ...

  - [materialize](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize) seems to be the solution.
- Use directives

  - I've found [angular2-materialize](https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize) to accomplish that
- Use Material component as Angular2 components

  - [material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) is the most advanced project I've found that provides this stuff.

It's a lot :D Also, I've found Material Design Lite for Angular2, but let it down because it seems it's going to be deprecated when Material2 will be out of Alpha.

**1) Will the three packages work well together ?** 
I didn't find any package yet that fills all the needs I listed.

Ok, so I started to install angular2-materialize, but I'm blocked with Webpack.
The Github readme tells, install MaterialCSS and angular2-materialize :

```
npm install materialize-css --save
npm install angular2-materialize --save
```

Then import materialize-css styles

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">
```

**2) What's the point to npm install locally the materialize-css package if we later include the css from cdn ?**

So I tried to find a way to include the css locally from node_modules/materialize-css... and here I'm blocked. The doc from NPM differs with Github, there's additional steps like adding alias, loaders and plugins in the webpack configuration.

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
  //... 
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      materializecss: 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css',
      materialize: 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js',
      //... 
    }
    //... 
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /materialize-css\/dist\/js\/materialize\.js/,
        loader: 'imports?materializecss'
      },
      //... 
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery",
          "window.jQuery": "jquery",
          Hammer: "hammerjs/hammer"
      })
  ]
  //... 
};
```

With this config, I thought I was able to do in my vendor.browser.ts something like :

```
import "materializecss";
```

And it would load and/or puts automatically the  pointing to the builded CSS. Or I am wrong and it doesn't work this way ?

Obviously it doesn't work and I get a :

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "materializecss" - vendor.browser.ts:23
```

Why ?

Thanks a lot for your help guys

Answer (score 2):

first do:

```
npm install materialize-css --save
npm install angular2-materialize --save
```

then:

```
import "materialize-css";
import { MaterializeDirective } from 'angular2-materialize';


@NgModule({declarations: [...MaterializeDirective],...})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your style.css

```
@import "~materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css";
```